# Using XSLT to select after EACH instance in a string/substring

Tags: xml, xslt, dublin-core

I'm attempting to write an XSLT stylesheet that will handle a Dublin Core (XML) cataloging record and create Chicago, APA, and MLA versions of the citation for each book. I've got everything worked out fine except the APA author one. APA's style for authors requires the author's last name (done), comma, first initial (done), any other initials (my stuck place problem).

What I have right now (and sample DC element is below):

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(dc:creator[1],',')" /><xsl:text>, </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-after(dc:creator[1],' '),1,1)" /><xsl:for-each select="dc:creator[position()!=1]"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="position()=last()"><xsl:text>., &amp; </xsl:text></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>., </xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,',')" /><xsl:text>, </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-after(.,' '),1,1)" /><xsl:if test="position()=last()">.</xsl:if></xsl:for-each>
```

For instances of the following format (what out catalog uses):

```
<dc:creator>Friend, Natasha</dc:creator>
```

this works just fine and returns: `Friend, N.`

But for

```
<dc:creator>Tolkien, J. R. R.</dc:creator>
```

it returns: `Tolkien, J.`

In a lot of cases it doesn't matter, but there will be cases where it really needs to return authors' middle initial(s), like `J.R.R. Tolkien` or `J.K. Rowling`.

So, I need to be able to return the letter that occurs after *each* space, not just the first instance of a space.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I. Here is an easy and natural XSLT 2.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:value-of separator=", " select=
  "substring-before(., ',')
   , for $n in tokenize(substring-after(., ','), '\s')[.]
        return
          substring($n, 1,1)
  "/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t xmlns:dc="some:dc">
 <dc:creator >Friend, Natasha</dc:creator>

 <dc:creator>Tolkien, J. R. R.</dc:creator>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
Friend, N
Tolkien, J., R., R.
```

---

**II. An XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*/text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ',')"/>

   <xsl:call-template name="replaceTokenDelims">
    <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select=
    "concat(normalize-space(substring-after(., ',')), ' ')"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pToken" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pReplacement" select="', '"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="replaceTokenDelims">
    <xsl:param name="pStr"/>
    <xsl:param name="pToken"/>
    <xsl:param name="pReplacement"/>

    <xsl:if test="$pStr">
     <xsl:value-of select="$pReplacement"/>
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "substring(substring-before($pStr, $pToken), 1, 1)"/>

     <xsl:call-template name="replaceTokenDelims">
      <xsl:with-param name="pStr"
           select="substring-after($pStr, $pToken)"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pToken" select="$pToken"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pReplacement" select="$pReplacement"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), again the same correct result is produced**:

```
Friend, N
Tolkien, J., R., R.
```

Comment: I'd been using 1.0 since I was more familiar with it, but I'll check that out, thank you. The return looks great except for the , after each, but I'll just take that out.

Comment: @Talia: I thaught that `, ` was wanted as the new delimiter. If not what should be the delimiter? I will also provide an XSLT 1.0 solution.

Comment: @Talia, Updated the answer with an added XSLT 1.0 solution.

Comment: Thank you for the XSLT 1.0 one. I'll experiment tonight/tomorrow with both. The delimiter ", " is wanted after the last name and after the final initial but not after any initials in between. APA style is...complicated. /sigh

Comment: @Talia, So, what should be the proper result for `Tolkien, J. R. R.` ?

Comment: Yes, that would be it. (as my brain is hitting useless-o-clock, I'm going to have to look at the 1.0 solution again in the morning. It doesn't seem to be returning just the first character and I need to figure out if it's that code or something in my other XSL)

Comment: @Talia, Please, what must be the result for `Tolkien, J. R. R.` ????? Please, also give an example with other names -- from the question as currently specified I understand that after the last name, only initials folow.

Comment: @Talia, I corrected both the XSLT 1.0 and the XSLT 2.0 solution to produce only the 1st letter of every non-first name.

Comment: Thank you, that works great! And yes, I realize now that it was a tricky case with the initials ones--for which it worked. But some authors had first-name, initial, which didn't work.

Comment: @Talia, You are welcome. So, what is still "not working"? Please, give an example and the exact wanted result.