# Using xslt to parse and then format names

Tags: xml, substring, xslt-1.0

I'm attempting to write an XSLT stylesheet that will handle author's names and create APA versions of the citation. The format for APA citation regarding author's name(s): Names are listed last name, then initials, if name(s) is the first element of the citation. Separate names with a comma, and an ampersand (&) before the last author. I followed Dimitre Novatchev's solution in this post:[Using XSLT to select after EACH instance in a string/substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665638/using-xslt-to-select-after-each-instance-in-a-string-substring) but I'm not getting the results I wanted.

**Input:**

```
<names>
    <author>Lio-Po, Gilda D.</author>
    <author>Primavera, Jurgenne H.</author>
    <author>Cuvin-Aralar, Ma. Lourdes A.</author>
    <author>Cruz, E.R.</author>
    <author>Catacutan, M.R.</author>
    <author>Agbayani, R.F.</author>
</names>
```

The desired output would be: **Lio-Po, G. D., Primavera, J. H., Cuvin-Aralar, M. L. A., Cruz, E. R., Catacutan, M. R., & Agbayani, R. F.**

**For records with just 2 authors:**

```
<names>
 <author>Lio-Po, Gilda D.</author>
 <author>Primavera, Jurgenne H.</author>
</names>
```

The desired output would be: **Lio-Po, G. D., & Primavera, J. H.**

Thanks in advance. Below is my code with some code taken from Dimitre's.

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/names/author">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(following-sibling::text()) = 1">
                <xsl:text>&amp; </xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(following-sibling::text()) != 0">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ',')"/>

    <xsl:call-template name="replaceTokenDelims">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="concat(normalize-space(substring-after(., ',')), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pToken" select="' '"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pReplacement" select="', '"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replaceTokenDelims">
    <xsl:param name="pStr"/>
    <xsl:param name="pToken"/>
    <xsl:param name="pReplacement"/>

    <xsl:if test="$pStr">
        <xsl:value-of select="$pReplacement"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-before($pStr, $pToken),1,1)"/>

        <xsl:call-template name="replaceTokenDelims">
            <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="substring-after($pStr, $pToken)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pToken" select="$pToken"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pReplacement" select="$pReplacement"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Running the above code gives me the output: **Lio-Po, G, D, Primavera, J, H, Cuvin-Aralar, M, L, A, Cruz, E, Catacutan, M, & Agbayani, R**

Comment: if I may ask, can we see your code that you tried

Comment: @Satya, i updated now my post with the code that I tried.

Comment: Something appears to have gone missing from your code; you have two templates followed by a for-each as a sibling.

Comment: euler, I think that your requirements aren't described in a clear and unambiguous way -- this is the main reason you still don't have the solution you need -- maybe you still don't have a (well-defined) problem? ...

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen, sorry, I'm new in stackoverflow and I'm having difficulty in placing the code since this is my first post. I have now edited the code, the two templates are actually after the for-each.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, my post is actually almost the same to this post [Using XSLT to select after EACH instance in a string/substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665638/using-xslt-to-select-after-each-instance-in-a-string-substring) and I don't know what you mean by unambiguous? I think I have stated what could be the probable values of names and their variations and my desired output?

Comment: euler, I don't see a set of rules described, that leaves no not-covered cases. Or if there is such a description, it is interspersed with other text, and can't be perceived as such.As for the previous question, I remember hard-trying to guess what the rules could have been.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, ok, I think the most important thing that I want is, given the input "Primavera, Jurgenne H.", I'd like it to be "Primavera, J. H." If the input is "Primavera, J.H.", I want to separate "J.H." with a space i.e. "J. H." If the input is only "Primavera, Jurgenne" or "Primavera, J.", the output would be just "Primavera, J." Nevermind those with interspersed text like "Jr." if that's what you mean. I hope I made my requirements clear now. Thank you so much for the time..

Comment: I have edited the code to illustrate variations in the input. The first 3 authors have their lastname, first name and middle initial; while the last 3 authors have only their last name and initials with no single space in between (e.g. Cruz, E.R.). I also replaced the code that I used since the previous code that I posted was just a snippet taken from a large xsl file. I tested the current code with the actual input xml that I posted above using Stylus Studio. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think I got it!**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/names/author">
        <xsl:variable name="firstname">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ', ')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="position() = last() and position() != 1">
            <xsl:text>&amp; </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring($firstname,2,1) = '.'">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(str:tokenize(.,','), ', ')"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize($firstname,'.')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'.')"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(str:tokenize(.,','), ', ')"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize($firstname,' ')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(.,1,1),'.')"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**If tested with the following input:**

```
<names>
    <author>Lio-Po, Gilda D.</author>
    <author>Cuvin-Aralar, Ma. Lourdes A.</author>
    <author>De la Cruz, Juan C.</author>
    <author>Cruz, E.R.</author>
    <author>Catacutan, M.R.</author>
    <author>De los Santos, M.A.</author>
    <author>Primavera, Jurgenne H.</author>
</names>
```

**The desired result is produced:**

```
Lio-Po, G. D., Cuvin-Aralar, M. L. A., De la Cruz, J. C., Cruz, E. R., Catacutan, M. R., De los Santos, M. A., & Primavera, J. H.
```

Comment: Many many thanks to mostafa.s.mirzaee for his code, I use some parts of it to achieve my desired output. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

This one works, I even tested it myself:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
<xsl:output  method="text" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/names/author">
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
        <xsl:text>&amp; </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(.,' ')">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="substring(.,2,1) = '.'">
            <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(.,'.')">           
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'.')"></xsl:value-of>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(.,1,1),'.')"></xsl:value-of>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>       
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>       

    </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

And the output for your given XML would be:

```
Lio-Po, G. D., Primavera, J. H., Cuvin-Aralar, M. L. A., Cruz, E. R., Catacutan, M. R., & Agbayani, R. F.,
```

If you can live with the last extra comma ;)

**APPEND:**
This is the full java code which I tested and looks ok.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

public class XLSTTester {

    public static void main(String[] params){
        try {
            transform("d:\\workspace1\\test.xml","d:\\workspace1\\test.xsl");
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void transform(String xmlFileFullPath, String xsltFileFullPath) throws TransformerException, IOException{
        File xmlFile = new File(xmlFileFullPath);
        File xsltFile = new File(xsltFileFullPath);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        javax.xml.transform.Source xmlSource = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(xmlFile);
        javax.xml.transform.Source xsltSource = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(xsltFile); 
        javax.xml.transform.Result transResult = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(sw);  

//          create an instance of TransformerFactory
        javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory transFact = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(  );

        javax.xml.transform.Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);
        trans.transform(xmlSource, transResult);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am receiving java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: http:..exslt.org.strings when I tried your code..

Comment: I appended my full java code, please try it and give me feedback. because I've run it successfully.

Comment: Mostafa, thank you so much for your effort, but I'm sorry to tell you that I'm just a newbie in xsl and I am not very familiar with java, hate to tell you this but honestly I don't know what to do with your attached java code. Regarding my desired output, I want to separate initials with one space in between (eg. Cruz, E.R. to Cruz, E. R.)

Comment: :) you are welcome euler, no problem friend. just tell me what is your xslt processor? isn't it a java built-in processor?

Comment: I am using stylus studio and previously while testing, I am using its built in processor, but when I switched it to use java built-in processor, your code worked! The output is not my desired output though.

Comment: Ok, good. I changed the XSLT so that your problem with "Cruz, E.R. to Cruz, E. R." is resolved now, please check and accept my answer :)

Comment: I am about to accept your answer after I tested your code and then I noticed that this will only work as desired if the authors have a single last name i.e. **De la Cruz, Juan C.** will return **De l. C. J. C.,**. The desired output would be **De la Cruz, J. C.** The source for authors will always have a comma and a space after their last name. I apologize for not anticipating about this multiple words last names. Lastly, it would be great if you can remove the very last comma;-) I tried to put it inside a variable and apply some templates but my knowledge with xsl is still very limited.

Comment: Managed to remove the extra comma by putting it inside a variable. `<xsl:value-of select="substring($citation-authors, 1, (string-length($citation-authors) - 2))"/>` since I noticed that your output contains 2 extra characters at the end, a comma and a space.

Comment: Ok, I leave rest of the job to yourself and other kind friends :)

Comment: Thank you so much mostafa, because of your code, I finally figured it out. Cheers!

Comment: I used some parts of your code, especially the parts that uses str:tokenize and rearranged some parts of it. I have posted my solution above. I did not use my original code posted above. I know that my solution is not the cleanest though I have attained my desired output, thanks to you. ;)