# Parse names using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm attempting to write an XSLT stylesheet that will handle author's names and format these as seen in Google scholar search results.

[image]

My goal is to follow the formatting of names as seen in the image (highlighted) above if for example I have this xml:

```
    <names>
        <author>Naylor, Rosamond L.</author>
        <author>Goldburg, Rebecca J.</author>
        <author>Primavera, Jurgenne H.</author>
        <author>Kautsky, Nils</author>
    </names>
```

The given names are not always "Last name, First name MI." format, it can also be just last name and initial(s), like this:

```
    <names>
        <author>Naylor, R.L.</author>
        <author>Goldburg, R. J.</author>
        <author>Primavera, J.H.</author>
        <author>Kautsky, Nils</author>
    </names>
```

If you'll ask me what have I tried so far, I will post it as an update. I'm still on the process of modifying the code I used for the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13983833/1919069) I posted here in SO a long time ago.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, post your code. (sample XML input and XSLT). thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

**XML**

```
<names>
    <author>Naylor, R.L.</author>
    <author>Goldburg, R. J.</author>
    <author>Primavera, J.H.</author>
    <author>Kautsky, Nils</author>
</names>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="upper-case" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

<xsl:template match="names">
        <xsl:for-each select="author">
            <xsl:variable name="first-names" select="substring-after(., ', ')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="translate($first-names, translate($first-names, $upper-case, ''), '')"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ', ')" />
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
RL Naylor, RJ Goldburg, JH Primavera, N Kautsky
```

**Caveat**:

There is no upper-case() function in XSLT 1.0. The above method will work with only with upper-case characters explicitly enumerated. If the text contains others (such as characters with diacritics) it will fail.

If that's a concern, it would be better to use something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="names">
        <xsl:for-each select="author">          
            <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(substring-after(., ', '),' .')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 1)" />
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ', ')" />
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

assuming your processor supports the EXSLT str:tokenize() function (if not, you will have to call a named recursive template to do the tokenizing).